# Creating a sass mixin with optional arguments

Tags: sass, less, scss-mixins

I am trying to create scss mixin for text styles, which includes color, font size, font weight, line height and font family. this is what i have done -

```
$color-gray-6: #777777;
$font-serif: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
$font-sans: 'Playfair Display', serif;


    @mixin font-style(
        $colour: $color-gray-6,
        $size: 1.6,
        $weight: 400,
        $line: $size * 1.5,
        $family: serif
    ) {
        @if $size {
            font-size: ($size * 1) + px;
            font-size: ($size / 10) + rem;
        }
        @if $line == 1 {
            line-height: 1;
        } @else {
            line-height: ($line * 1) + px;
            line-height: ($line / 10) + rem;
        }
        @if $colour {
            color: $colour;
        }
        @if $weight {
            font-weight: $weight;
        }
        @if $family == serif {
            font-family: $font-serif;
        } @else {
            font-family: $font-sans;
        }
    }
```

I am using the mixing as - `@include font-style(#000000, 14, 400, sans)`

**Problem -** When I am not passing line height getting this error - Undefined operation "sans * 1. I think when line height is not present it is treating font family as 4th parameter.

**Question -** Is there any way to make the 4th parameter optional, or if there is any better way please sugges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth parameter or your `font-style()` mixin is `$line`. You haven't skipped over it when you pass in `sans` as the argument. Instead you've taken what should be the fifth argument and made it the fourth.

The best approach you can take is to use "keyword arguments": https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#keyword-arguments

Essentially you need to tell the mixin which argument it is that you're supplying.

Example:

```
@include font-style(#000, 14, 400, $family: sans);
```